# Derivative of an integral $\sqrt{t}\sin t dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I need to find the derivative of this function. I know I need to separate the integrals into two and use the chain rule but I am stuck.

$$y=\int_\sqrt{x}^{x^3}\sqrt{t}\sin t~dt~.$$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me show you a general method which works in these sorts of situations.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we know how to take the derivative of
$$
F(z):=\int_0^z\sqrt{t}\sin(t)\,dt;
$$
in particular, FTC tells us that 
$$\tag{1}
F'(z)=\sqrt{z}\sin(z).
$$
Now, note that
$$
\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x^3}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)\,dt=\int_0^{x^3}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)\,dt-\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)\,dt=F(x^3)-F(\sqrt{x}).
$$
So, the derivative you want is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[F(x^3)-F(\sqrt{x})\right].
$$
See if you can use the Chain Rule, and (1), to finish it up from here.

Comment: As written, your first term doesn't have a sine in it.  Applying the chain rule gives us $$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[F(x^3)-F(\sqrt{x})\right]=3x^2F'(x^3)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}F'(             \sqrt{x}).$$
Now, use (1) to simplify.

Comment: @Shan Everything is write other than that missing sine in the $\sqrt{x}$ term.

Comment: I am sorry I typed it in wrong from my paper. I had meant that I had (-4th root(x) sin(sqrt(x)))/(2sqrt(x))+sqrt(x^3)sin(x^3)(3x^2)

Comment: No, not in the denominator.  Remember, $F'(z)=\sqrt{z}\sin(z)$; so, $F'(\sqrt{x})=\sqrt[4]{x}\sin(\sqrt{x})$. Plug that (and the similar expression for $F'(x^3)$, in to the statement in my previous comment.

Comment: Still not quite right.  Instead of multiplying your last term by $\sqrt{x}$, you should be multiplying it by $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ (i.e. the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ with respect to $x$), as per the formula I gave in a previous comment.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying the math symbols but I think I got the right answer. If you could give me 5 more minutes I am trying to post it using the right symbols. By the way I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: There we go this is what I got and if I followed your instructions which I very carefully tried my best to (taking my first Calculus class).$$\sqrt{{x^3}}\sin({x^3}){3x^2}-{\sqrt[4]{x}\sin(\sqrt{x})\over2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: @Shan Looks great!

Comment: Thank you so much Nicholas. Looks like I was correct the first time I did it on my paper. I just had trouble typing it in. Looks like mathematical expressions and regular keyboards don't go together. Again thank you. I have my Calculus 1 final tomorrow so I just wanted make sure I knew how to one of these tougher problems.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

By the chain rule we prove easly:

If 
$$F(x)=\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt$$
then
$$F'(x)=f(v(x))v'(x)-f(u(x))u'(x)$$